# How to make simple interacting with running python script for web?

Tags: python, html, web

I have a running loop script in Python, which I want interact with a HTML-page. For example:

> (HTML)Clicking button -> magic -> (Python) Do something function in
>   script.py

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474557/interact-with-python-script-running-infinitive-loop-from-web) is not appropriate for this.

Comment: I see only statements, what is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resole this  problem by PIPE in python. Python script reads file **p1.txt** by line and server.js sends text. For example, here server.js sends string **'COMMAND'** and we are getting script.py response.

> script.py

```
import os,sys
fd = "./p1.txt"
try:
    os.mkfifo(fd)
except OSError:
    pass
rp = os.open(fd, os.O_RDONLY)

#Need to create new thread, for background reading file
while True:
    response = os.read(rp, 54)
    if response == "COMMAND":
        #do
        print 'ICATCHYOU'
```

> server.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = '/home/pi/develop/p1.txt';

var streamOptions = { flags: 'w',
                      encoding: 'utf-8',
                      mode: 0666 };

var afterOpen = function(err, fd) {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path, streamOptions);   
    writeStream.write("COMMAND");
};


fs.open(path, 'w', afterOpen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use Selenium python binding for the purpose of interecting with Web page with your python script.

[Selenium link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html)

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```